# Finding equation relating  and δ.

Tags: trigonometry

Newbie here. Just want to ask step on how to make the equation relating  and δ using basic trigonometry.

[image]
By the way, the problem required that the area of the tilted quadrilateral A in right figure be equal with the area of the un-tilted quadrilateral A.

Based on that, I got the following:
$$x_2 h + \frac{1}{2}a h=x_2y+\frac{1}{2}by$$

I'm not sure if the equation above is correct or useful, but I guess what I need is to find trigonometric equations to remove $x_2$, $h$, $y$, $a$, and $b$ . I'm having a hard time making right triangles to use the SOCAH TOA method. Please help.

Comment: What is the SOCAH TOA method?

Comment: Ah. SOH is sin(angle)=opposite side / hypotenuse. CAH is cos(angle)=adjacent side / hypotenuse. TOA is tan(angle)=opposite side / adjacent side

Answer (score 0):

Hint: eliminate $\alpha$ from $\psi+\alpha=\pi/2\,,\quad \alpha+\delta=\pi/2\,.$

[image]

Comment: While I strongly suspect it was the intent, I find nothing in the diagrams that actually requires the upper and lower lines of $A$ in the right-hand diagram to be parallel, and thus that the left-hand side of $A$ in that diagram is vertical, as your diagram assumes.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for joining the discussion. To make this easier I added a few labels because I did not quite understand your comment. Note that OP's segment $y$ is not identical to my segment $QS\,.$ In short: I rotated $y$ so that its angle with $QU$ becomes 90 degrees and therefore parallel to $TP$.

Comment: I was not referring to the lines of length $y$, but rather to the far left border of the gray area, that serves as the right terminus of the angle $\psi$ in the right diagram of the post. That line when extended to the base corresponds to the line $\overline{PR}$ in your diagram, which you assert is perpendicular to the base. I find it very likely this was the intent (at least, the equivalent condition that the top and bottom lines on $A$ are to be parallel, so $\delta + 2\gamma = \pi$), but I see nothing that actually requires it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair From OP's left picture I gather that $x_2+a=x_1\,.$ From the right one I gather $x_2+b=x_1\,.$ So $a=b\,.$ Then I think we get that $PR$ is perpendicular to the base since the two $y$'s in the right picture are parallel.

Comment: $x_2+b = x_1$ supposes that the top and bottom lines are parallel. If they are, the two $y$ lines must be parallel as well, and cut off a length of $x_2$ from $x_1$, leaving $b$ behind. But if the top and bottom lines are not parallel, then neither are the $y$ lines, and the length they cut off from the top line will not be $x_2$, so $x_2 +b \ne x_1$. Both are possible.